# Animating and hiding Banner Admob

Tags: ios, swift, admob, banner

I am considering displaying my Admob banner ad (320 x 50) within my upper navigation bar.  Currently, my app logo is shown on the top of the navigation bar.

My question is, can I show my logo for 2 seconds (hiding the advert) then show the advert for 35seconds (hiding the logo)... and repeat?  (Doing a quick animation between the two)...

If this is possible, what is the correct procedure for removing the banner add?  Is this just a case of hiding the UIView (GADBannerView) and AdMob recognises that the BannerAd is not shown?  Or would I have to dismiss the BannerAd and request a new one - how is this possible? 
(Like how the video adverts work - requesting a new video advert when the current video is dismissed).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a simple case of hiding the UIView. It is recommended that you use one banner ad for the complete lifecycle of the app.

If you're going to be showing it and hiding it often, you're not going to want to request another ad, as this is unnecessary given that there's no harm in using the same banner multiple times. Also, the ad automatically refreshes every 45-90 seconds, which means that you should never have to re-request it.

Comment: Cheers Nik, thats great thanks.
Am I right in saying that the ad has to be on the screen for minimum of 30seconds to count as an impression?

Comment: @M.Strachan No problem. As for you question, I'm not too sure, although that does make sense. If you read that somewhere, then I'm sure it's true, or close to true. Makes sense though